# QQmlPropertyMap in propery QQmlPropertyMap

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a class that can create dynamic properties without Q_PROPERTY

```
//myclass.h
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlPropertyMap>
class MyClass : public QQmlPropertyMap
{
public:
    static MyClass& instance();
    ~MyClass() override = default;
    Q_DISABLE_COPY_MOVE(MyClass)
private:
    explicit MyClass();
};
QObject *qmlMyClassInterface(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine);

//myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QTimer>
QObject *qmlMyClassInterface(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) {
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
    MyClass *p = &MyClass::instance();
    engine->setObjectOwnership(p, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
    return p;
}
MyClass &MyClass::instance() {
    static MyClass singleton;
    return singleton;
}
MyClass::MyClass() {
    insert("Test1", "Test 1");
    insert("Test2", "Test 2");
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, [this]{
        insert("Test1", "Update test 1");
        insert("Test2", "Update test 2");});
}

//main.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClass>("MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass", qmlMyClassInterface);

//main.qml
import MyClass 1.0
title: MyClass.Test1
text: MyClass.Test2
```

Is it possible in the property QQmlPropertyMap have QQmlPropertyMap. To get a subproperty. Something like this in qml:

```
text: MyClass.Test2.SubTest1
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: maybe OP just wants to show it off -)

Comment: I'm not very friendly with English. I wanted to ask how to make a dynamic subproperty like in the last example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. In myclass.h declare

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QQmlPropertyMap*)
```

In the constructor of MyClass

```
QQmlPropertyMap *subProperty = new QQmlPropertyMap(this);
subProperty->insert("SubTest1", "some text");

QVariant stored;
stored.setValue(subProperty);
insert("Test2", stored);

QTimer::singleShot(3000, [subProperty]{
        subProperty->insert("SubTest1", "Update some text");
});
```

Now in qml you can do this

```
text: MyClass.Test2.SubTest1
```

Thanks to this, you can create dynamic properties and sub-properties without Q_PROPERTY and change values ​​from C ++, all changes will be notified in qml